# Why Jedburgh kill the Senator and his agents?

Tags: plot-explanation, edge-of-darkness

In *Edge of Darkness* (2010), the senator was helping Jedburgh in all his activities.

But at the climax, Jedburgh shot the agents in the head and killed the senator.

So why did Jedburgh kill the senator and his agents?

Answer (score 1):

### Because he switched sides.

Jedburgh was hired to 'handle' Craven but liked him and so let him investigate for his own reasons.

As for the senator...he was trying to "spin" the incident into a positive and Jedburgh didn't agree...

> Jedburgh, who is revealed to be suffering from a terminal illness, meets with Moore, the Senator (for whom he had been working) and the political advisor who assigned Jedburgh to eliminate Craven.
>
> He listens to their suggestions as to how to play the Northmoor incident in a positive light. **He tells them that he is done** and then suggests an assassination attempt on the Senator should be the feature story, to drive Bennetts death out of the tabloids.
>
> They are happy to go along with the story until **Jedburgh tells the senator that he is on the wrong side of the equation**. Jedburgh then pulls out his gun and shoots all three men dead.
>
> <sup>[IMDB Synopsis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1226273/synopsis?ref_=tt_stry_pl)</sup>